# Understanding the 'this' keyword in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have started to learn VueJS from scratch. I am following their official Guide. But I am stuck here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input

In this example...

```
var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

..how is it that the `message` property is directly being accessed without any reference to the `data` object? If `this` keyword refers to the current Vue instance, shouldn't the `message` property be accessed like this: `this.data.message`?

Consider the following example:

```
({
  name: "John Doe",
  data: {
    message: "Hello World"
  },
  greet: function(){
    console.log("I am " + this.name);
    console.log("I have a message for you: " + this.data.message); //see here
  }
}).greet();
```

This is how I would have accessed a property in vanilla javascript. Can someone please make me understand what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: `this` isn't always bound lexically. It can also be bound with `call`, `apply`, or `bind`, which is likely what VueJS is doing.

Comment: The object you pass to `new Vue()` and the object it returns are *not* the same object. You pass it an object it uses to *create* the Vue. Part of that process is making the data properties, methods, computeds, etc available as properties of the created object.

Comment: Basically It has proxy that makes `this.$data.property` accesible as `this.property`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vue,   Vue instance proxy  properties of data and methods by using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: This is correct for Vue 3 but was not correct for Vue 2 at all.

Answer (score 6):

Read this: [Options / Data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

From that we get "The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”." Meaning everything in the `data` object property is applied directly to the new `Vue`. This makes thos properties available on `this` as getters and setters.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also included the documention about the "methods" option, which is currently: `Methods to be mixed into the Vue instance. You can access these methods directly on the VM instance, or use them in directive expressions. All methods will have their this context automatically bound to the Vue instance.`

Comment: You're right, and your answer was helpful to me.  I only added the comment in case you cared to update your answer with additional information.  But that's up to you, obviously.

Answer (score -1):

`this` is special object. When compiled, (yes, it is compiled!) the `data` keyword would disappear. All the properties and methods will wrap to a new object, so this can now conform to the JS rules.

Comment: "so this can now conform to the JS rules". There's no magic here. You don't need preprocessing or compilation to achieve this, this has always been possible in JavaScript.

Comment: It is how vue engine works, i mean vue engine or libs preprocessing it. If not compiled(or translated, how can browser know it