# Is is proper to use "this" when referencing variables in vuejs v-if expressions?

Tags: vue.js

Many of the examples for v-if use unqualified variable names such as:

```
<h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
```

but I am wondering of the following code is equivalent?

```
<h1 v-if="this.awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
```

It seems to work correctly but I'm seeking some guidance on pros/cons of doing this.

The reason I ask is because when specifying v-if, "this" is **not recommended**, but when developing computed properties, "this" is **required** to reference model variables.

This makes things inconsistent for developers.

From the vue.js source code, they are using the javascript "with" statement to evaluate v-if tags to eliminate the need for the "this" qualifier.  However, use of "with" is generally discouraged here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

I personally don't want to use "this" on v-if but it'd be even nicer to not have to use it in computed properties as well.

Comment: No, there is no `this` in vue template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the 'this' keyword in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505736/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-vue)

Comment: In most cases you can use it but it is simply unnecessary and officially discouraged by the recommended linting rules: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/this-in-template.md

Comment: A major con is `this` makes the template more verbose than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Vue template Keys are actually keys that are evaluated against component instance. These two snippets are equivalent, so `this` can be omitted.

`this` is needed in Vue templates in case of dynamic keys, e.g. for `this[this.awesome]`:

```
<h1 v-if="this[awesome]">Vue is awesome!</h1>
```

This is rarely needed in practice because a cleaner way is to move `awesome` access into computed property or a method.